# Fazer aparecer o MODAL do Boostrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, modal

Boa tarde Pessoal

Sou iniciante no desenvolvimento WEb e não estou conseguindo **exibir o modal do boostrap** no meu Projeto. O botão aparece normal, porém ao clicar nele, não exibe o modal.

A minha pergunta principal é: Será que devo importar outras bibliotecas, ou esse import que mostrei lá embaixo ja é o suficiente para usar todas os componentes do Bootstrap?

Meu código está assim:

**HTML e Javascript - **Modal.vue**, Componete criado:**

```
<template>
  <div v-bind:id="nome" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1"v-bind:arialabelledby="nome">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <slot></slot>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      props:['nome']
    }
</script>
```

**Formulario Criado dentro do modal:**

```
<modal nome="meuModalTeste">

  <form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Endereço de email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Seu email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Nunca vamos compartilhar seu email, com ninguém.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Senha</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Senha">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Clique em mim</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**Para adicionar um botão que abre o modal:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#meuModalTeste">Modal grande</button>
```

Eu vi em alguns sites, inclusive aqui no StackOverflow que deveria importar algumas bilbiotecas do BOOTSTRAP nos meus **imports**,mas como podem ver ja tem o import do boostrap.

```
// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Deveria aparecer esse modal, como podem ver na imagem abaixo, mas ao clicar no botão, nada é exibido, nem escurece a tela, que normalmente acontece quando nao tem nenhum conteúdo. O que será que estou fazendo de errado? Agradeco desde já a ajuda de vocês.

[image: Foto tirada do Curso que estou fazendo]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -3):

`data-target="#meuModalTeste"` no seu botão que aciona o modal é referente ao id que você deu a div do modal, como ao que parece você deu um name para a tag e não um id, consequentemente o modal não funciona.

```
<div id="meuModalTeste">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Endereço de email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Seu email">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Nunca vamos compartilhar seu email, com ninguém.</small>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Senha</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Senha">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Clique em mim</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Alterei a tag `modal` para `div` e dei um id `meuModalTeste` para ela ao invés de um `name`. Aqui tem um exemplo da própria documentação que deve ser interessante [Modal - Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Pedro nao funcionou , até tentei cara .Na verdade o que eu fiz foi dar um ID dinamico para o meu modal, com props ['nome'] , ou seja, quando abro a tag <modal nome="#meuModalTeste"> , ele passa o parametro nome para o ID que está la no arquivo onde tem o div do arquivo Modal.vue.

Answer (score -3):

O caminho mais fácil seria você ir ao site do Bootstrap. Olha o 5.2, por exemplo: [ https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/ ]. Lá você clica em Modal e seleciona um exemplo. Copia o exemplo completo e cola no teu site. Veja se funciona.
Alguns itens do Bootstrap precisam de scripts adicionais para funcionar, como as Tooltips, por exemplo. Você precisa iniciá-las. Tudo isso você pode ver nos exemplos do site.
Veja se consegue e nos avise! : )